# What is the best IPC method for first process to remain running while subsequent processes pass params only?

Tags: c++, c, ipc, native

I need to develop a process that starts and continues running when no other such process is running on the local host. Subsequent local instances of this process (spawned by other processes, i.e. not forked child/parent) then need to execute only to somehow pass their command line parameters to the original process for processing and then exit as soon as possible.

I know I need IPC to achieve this while I need to keep the overhead of both footprint and execution speed to a bare minimum, so this rules out sockets and other network based IPC such as message queues.
The spawned processes need to somehow be aware of the master process. There is no requirement for IPC across hosts.

I'm thinking about using a named pipe but want to know the alternatives. For example, would an anonymous pipe via a shared handle written to file be more efficient?

In this case the mechanism is important; not the language and environment contained in examples. I will implement the mechanism in C or C++.

Comment: What platform?  The answers will be very different for Windows, Posix, and RTOS platforms.

Comment: Do you have performance figures that show sockets are too slow?  Make it easy to understand first, then optimize.

Comment: Ultimately, it will run on Windows and the (old) big four Unix. I can't baseline the performance, I instead just have to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: Why can't I baseline the performance? I can but I'm developing something that no-one particularly wants so it will be used as a scapegoat for the poor performance of other system components if it performs anything less than optimally. For example; if I use System V, someone will complain that it's a bottleneck and I should have used pipes instead.

Answer (score 0):

The MAN page for `msgrcv()` and `msgsnd()` give everything you need to know to perform the desired operations.

Suggest reading: [how to use msgrcv](https://gist.github.com/Mark-htmlgogogo/e024c36541646373581472348657304d)   for an example of how to use those functions.

Comment: On my OS  (ubuntu linux) the information for both functions are on the same MAN page